# How can I learn the basics of SharePoint 2016 new features in few days?

Tags: 2016

I have the knowledge of SharePoint 2010 & 2013 as a basics like OOTB webpart, workflow, infopath and little bit knowledge of the custom development- custom webpart, workflow, Power-shell scripting.

As per the above information, can anyone let me know the source / links to clear the basics of SharePoint 2016 for the beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Your question will not lead to any particular answer. There may be lots of possible answer.

You can just google **SharePoint 2016** and you will get a lots of help. Choose Microsoft links to get latest updates.

Few of the conceptual links are:-

- [New and improved features in SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346121(v=office.16).aspx)
- [What's New in SharePoint 2016: Features Overview](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/whats-new-in-sharepoint-2016)

And many more.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the url to learn features overview of sharepoint 2016.

http://en.share-gate.com/blog/whats-new-in-sharepoint-2016